# I can update to Linux Kernel 4.9?

Tags: updates, kernel

how are you?
I want update to **kernel 4.9**, but I not know if this can cause problems in my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always try to upgrade you kernel.

However, as there is no 4.9 kernel package in elementary OS, you should understand the risks (as in: your system will not boot any more or there will be driver errors; there is only a very small chance of danger as in actually bricking it).

If you are sure to go on with the upgrade, I would start at http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.9/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install 4.9 on my machine without issue. I used Ukuu which makes the process fairly painless and allows you to easily revert back if you have issues.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/upgrade-kernel-ukuu-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

I had update my kernel to 4.6 trying to fix some flickering in chrome caused by skylake intel processor but not success. I think you can upgrade to 4.9 carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I have two machines on Loki - one running latest 4.8 and other 4.9 and both run.  As long as you use the Ubuntu packages, your old kernels will still be bootable via Grub.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I upgraded to 4.9 on my skylake laptop with no issues at all. As others said, you retain the ability to boot from the stock kernel with grub.